Convergence in Hausdorff distance $\iff$ Lebesgue measure converges
There are numerous sources (e.g. here) mentioning that Lebesgue measure is not continuous with respect to the Hausdorff distance $d_H$. This means that for a sequence of sets $K_n$ converging to $K$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_H(K_n,K)=0 \ \ \mathrm{does \ not \ imply \ that} \ \ \mathrm{Leb}(K) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \mathrm{Leb}(K_n).$$
There are a few cases in which the above implication is true and I was wondering why it turns out to be true in my problem, or why my working is incorrect.
Recall that for sets $A$ and $B$
$$d_H(A,B):=\inf\{r>0 \ | \ A\subset B_r(B), \ B \subset B_r(A)\}.$$
Now let $K_n$ be a sequence of intervals converging to the singleton $\{k\}$ where $\{k\}\subset K_n$ for each $n$ (for example, $K_n=[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $k=0$). By the above definition
\begin{align}
d_H(K_n,\{k\})&=\inf\{r>0 \ | \ K_n\subset B_r(\{k\}), \ \{k\} \subset B_r(K_n)\}\\
&=\inf\{r>0 \ | \ K_n\subset B_r(\{k\})\}\\
&=\mathrm{Leb}(K_n).
\end{align}
Therefore $d_H(K_n,\{k\})\to 0 \iff\mathrm{Leb}(K_n)\to 0 = \mathrm{Leb}(\{k\})$. Is the above correct? or where am I going wrong?

This comment is not helpful and snarky. I am aware that finding one example doesn't mean it works for all examples. I am mealy wondering why it is true in my setting.

You wrote $ d_H(K_n,{k})\to 0 \iff\mathrm{Leb}(K_n)\to 0 = \mathrm{Leb}({k}) $ which I took to mean a belief that you'd somehow proven the general statement.  It is a frustrating question to ask "why" something is true without elaboration.  This is similar to asking "I know not all numbers are prime, but I picked a random number, 13, and it turned out to be prime.  Why?"

An interesting question might be "what are sufficient or necessary criteria one could impose for the sequence of sets to have this property of convergence in Lebesgue measure?" but I didn't see you asking that question.

@JakeMirra I disagree. If you had read the contents of my post it would have been made clear that this is not what I am claiming. Irrespective, you should have a long hard look at yourself and touch up on your manners mate. The way you phased your comment was extremely condescending.

If I didn't understand the contents of your post, it's because it's poorly written, not because I was cruising around MSE looking for someone I could condescend to.  No one else answered your question, most likely because it's not clear what you're asking. I may look in the mirror today but I promise it won't be because you told me to.
